# jetty java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Tags: jetty-9

I am trying to replace self signed jetty certificate by signed one.
I replaced 2 files jetty.crt and jetty.key.Run 2 commands :

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

now jetty doesn't start. Here are logs :

2015-08-20 14:11:08.719:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@695a22ad: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 3):

We had the similar problem.

After importing the newly generated pkcs12 keystore to the destination keystore, I ran

> keytool -keypasswd -keystore path_to_your_keystore_file -alias your_key_alias -storetype JKS

set the keypassword as we used before and jetty started running.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is a passwords mismatch into file: 
jetty-ssl.xml

One of the solution would be to generate a password as explained here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Passwords

and copy/paste this password to jetty-ssl.xml file :

```
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="OBF:paste_here_password"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default="OBF:paste_here_password"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.truststore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default="OBF:paste_here_password"/></Set>
```

NOTE: 
1. On jetty 9 don't paste password in plain text it must be encrypted password generated by jetty utility. Here is an instruction how to get the password :
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Passwords
2. To avoid confusions you can simply use the same password in all three instances into the file 
jetty-ssl.xml for:
jetty.keystore.password
jetty.keymanager.password
jetty.truststore.password